# What would the correct SSL configuration be for a Docker image running Nginx on Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, docker, nginx, h2

I'm creating a Dockerfile to run on Azure with Nginx for a static site. All app services that use this Docker image will run with forced redirect to SSL and H2.

How should I configure these values to leverage the SSL settings on my app service in Azure?  It's not clear what Azure does behind the scenes when binding SSL to the domain.

```
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/##DOMAIN##/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/##DOMAIN##/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Azure has nothing to with your case until unless you are using a Load Balancer which terminates SSL. So you question is a bit unclear as to what you are looking for?

Comment: I know how to configure NGINX for SSL on Ubuntu or other Linux VM's.  However, on Azure a docker image is used.  I need to know how to configure my .conf files so that they take on the settings i've set on my azure app service for running SSL with a Site Certificate and a mapped domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Azure App Service team: You do not need to worry about SSL configuration on your Docker image because we take care of it upstream. The only thing you need to worry about is if someone is coming over http, redirect them to https using the X-ARR-SSL header at nginx level.

For example,

```
 if ($http_x_arr_ssl = "") {
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }
```